# Throttling Data Renders in React

Tags: reactjs

I am shooting for great performance, and I know one way to do this is to throttle data loading when the user would not initially see all the data on load.

What is the best method of doing this in React?

I currently have an Array of Data and I only show 2-4 records at a time on the screen depending on device used.

My initial plan for doing this was to call a function that did:

```
incrementalLoad(data, item) { for(let i in data) { setTimeout(() => { //load 8 records }, 1000) }
```

But then I remembered the event loop and stack management is a problem here. What kind of solutions have you all used? Am I in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by throttle data loading? Do you mean limit the number of in-flight ajax calls? Or throttle how many times react renders when data is loaded?

Comment: @AndyRay My first instinct is to update state of the component to update the list with the new data so that I can stick with one ajax call and limit network demand. So I am going to change the title to data render. Thanks

Comment: @AndyRay Oh, that brings up an idea, can I have two states. One state in the component for all the data and one state for all data that is currently displayed. And everytime it renders have a setTimeoute function that appends the current state with 10 more items from the "all data" state. Seems like a bigO(n^2) in memory allocation though ...

Comment: Performance probably isn't a concern here. Can you clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish? React doesn't know anything about your data, how to fetch it, or where it came from. If you're trying to throttle ajax calls, use underscore.throttle or any throttle npm package. the package `throat` can throttle in flight promises as well. if you're trying to throttle react renders, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a virtual list. Basically, you have a bunch of records loaded in memory, but you only render the ones that are visible on screen. As you scroll, items are added/removed from the DOM as needed.

The react-virtualized library (https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) has a great implementation for this sort of behavior. You can see a bunch of demos of its usage here: https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/components/List

Comment: I will try implementing this, and then confirm tomorrow. Sounds on point.